# Apple Maps Not Showing Map Overlay

Tags: mapkit, geojson, apple-maps

I have a question regarding creating a Apple Map Overlay. I am trying to set on odd shape overlay from a JSON file. I have researched this on Stack Overflow, and have tried many of the solutions, but none seem to work. My code is below:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.mapType = .standard

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.TapGesture))
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            if overlay is MKPolygon {
                let polygonView = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
                polygonView.strokeColor = UIColor.black
                polygonView.lineWidth = 0.5
                polygonView.fillColor = UIColor.blue
                return polygonView
            }
            return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }

    @objc func TapGesture(gesRect: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let location = gesRect.location(in: mapView)
        coordinate = mapView.convert(location,toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

        let locCoord = mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        print("Tapped at lat: \(locCoord.latitude) long: \(locCoord.longitude)")
        print("Tapped at: \(location)")

        self.retreiveShape() { (full_shape) in

            if let shape = full_shape {

                let polygon = MKPolygon.init(coordinates: shape, count: shape.count)

                self.mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
            } else {
                print("ARRAY EMPTY")
            }
        }
    }

   func retreiveShape(completion: @escaping ([CLLocationCoordinate2D]?) -> ()) {

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "shape", ofType: "json")
        var coord_array = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        do {
            let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path!))
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] {

                if let shape = dictionary["shape"] as? Array<Any>  {

                    for regions in shape {

                        guard let region = regions as? Array<Array<Array<Double>>> else {
                            print("NOT HAPPENING")
                            return
                        }
                        for sections in region {
                            for coord in sections {
                                print("LATITUDE: \(coord[0])", "LONGITUDE: \(coord[1])")
                                let coordinatesToAppend = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord[0], longitude: coord[1])
                                coord_array.append(coordinatesToAppend)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    completion(coord_array)
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

The shape.json file is below:

```
{
    "shape":[
        [
            [
                [-81.621199, 30.282314],
                [-81.613987, 30.281941],
                [-81.611277, 30.284743],
                [-81.602735, 30.284026],
                [-81.601978, 30.292561],
                [-81.596275, 30.290861],
                [-81.592406, 30.290182],
                [-81.571146, 30.28763],
                [-81.55922, 30.286602],
                [-81.559148, 30.291132],
                [-81.558633, 30.294747],
                [-81.55881, 30.312887],
                [-81.558601, 30.312888],
                [-81.558622, 30.316235],
                [-81.558313, 30.316828],
                [-81.552252, 30.320252],
                [-81.548471, 30.321618],
                [-81.527882, 30.323989],
                [-81.529486, 30.328076],
                [-81.537635, 30.336704],
                [-81.537706, 30.337221],
                [-81.538717, 30.338277],
                [-81.539343, 30.338462],
                [-81.542809, 30.341686],
                [-81.547286, 30.345211],
                [-81.552498, 30.348839],
                [-81.552559, 30.352445],
                [-81.577566, 30.352039],
                [-81.578098, 30.353324],
                [-81.578161, 30.35642],
                [-81.577294, 30.3596],
                [-81.576996, 30.366609],
                [-81.58011, 30.366553],
                [-81.580875, 30.37062],
                [-81.580844, 30.373862],
                [-81.581462, 30.374486],
                [-81.578114, 30.374236],
                [-81.572908, 30.374611],
                [-81.562232, 30.372303],
                [-81.551965, 30.366559],
                [-81.548676, 30.365568],
                [-81.540187, 30.378172],
                [-81.538175, 30.380467],
                [-81.538213, 30.387239],
                [-81.536613, 30.388739],
                [-81.512612, 30.392739],
                [-81.505211, 30.390739],
                [-81.490911, 30.392139],
                [-81.49085, 30.389014],
                [-81.489978, 30.389207],
                [-81.488818, 30.38775],
                [-81.489203, 30.389266],
                [-81.487056, 30.390019],
                [-81.481446, 30.391262],
                [-81.479505, 30.39117],
                [-81.477708, 30.390635],
                [-81.476792, 30.390609],
                [-81.476244, 30.391002],
                [-81.473212, 30.389422],
                [-81.472125, 30.388436],
                [-81.472225, 30.388071],
                [-81.474072, 30.386758],
                [-81.475085, 30.384287],
                [-81.474394, 30.381898],
                [-81.473246, 30.38059],
                [-81.473337, 30.380112],
                [-81.47295, 30.379864],
                [-81.472643, 30.380053],
                [-81.471914, 30.379532],
                [-81.471629, 30.378346],
                [-81.470845, 30.377256],
                [-81.468671, 30.376016],
                [-81.466871, 30.374481],
                [-81.465402, 30.374424],
                [-81.464374, 30.373764],
                [-81.465116, 30.373015],
                [-81.467728, 30.372493],
                [-81.469102, 30.371435],
                [-81.470279, 30.369931],
                [-81.472008, 30.370608],
                [-81.473695, 30.370041],
                [-81.471862, 30.370238],
                [-81.470952, 30.369737],
                [-81.471715, 30.369462],
                [-81.470506, 30.369378],
                [-81.469456, 30.368207],
                [-81.468051, 30.367707],
                [-81.46754, 30.366828],
                [-81.466905, 30.366464],
                [-81.467432, 30.366219],
                [-81.466928, 30.365735],
                [-81.465222, 30.365136],
                [-81.464909, 30.364103],
                [-81.46316, 30.362764],
                [-81.463369, 30.36188],
                [-81.462197, 30.361235],
                [-81.461151, 30.36123],
                [-81.46117, 30.360531],
                [-81.461878, 30.360305],
                [-81.461619, 30.359642],
                [-81.461873, 30.358669],
                [-81.461645, 30.358376],
                [-81.460504, 30.358329],
                [-81.46288, 30.357969],
                [-81.462786, 30.357137],
                [-81.461247, 30.355282],
                [-81.460556, 30.352518],
                [-81.46184, 30.340222],
                [-81.462497, 30.339325],
                [-81.465064, 30.337897],
                [-81.471588, 30.328301],
                [-81.472988, 30.318258],
                [-81.469123, 30.319481],
                [-81.450496, 30.320896],
                [-81.443818, 30.302908],
                [-81.442451, 30.301512],
                [-81.438991, 30.299798],
                [-81.437921, 30.298031],
                [-81.437696, 30.284657],
                [-81.438134, 30.283427],
                [-81.439935, 30.281191],
                [-81.440578, 30.279729],
                [-81.440309, 30.276152],
                [-81.441217, 30.271746],
                [-81.440891, 30.270368],
                [-81.440247, 30.269313],
                [-81.438555, 30.267721],
                [-81.43765, 30.266188],
                [-81.43705, 30.257116],
                [-81.441869, 30.256519],
                [-81.45385, 30.252008],
                [-81.466184, 30.251073],
                [-81.472173, 30.251296],
                [-81.491372, 30.251034],
                [-81.507105, 30.253603],
                [-81.510744, 30.253761],
                [-81.530261, 30.250144],
                [-81.56957, 30.249854],
                [-81.584658, 30.251369],
                [-81.586895, 30.251326],
                [-81.589607, 30.250593],
                [-81.593308, 30.248471],
                [-81.605497, 30.260294],
                [-81.621493, 30.282334],
                [-81.621199, 30.282314]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

It should create an odd shape overlay in the Southside of Jacksonville,FL, but it isn't. When the completion block is called the Coordinates are added to the array, but the map overlay isn't showing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the same code work with a simpler (and perhaps shorter) list of vertices? If so, you can start adding points until it stops working, and that may give you an idea of where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is somewhat embarrassing. I did as was suggested in the comments, and tried having the shape with nine vertices. It still didn't work. I then changed the coord from:

```
print("LATITUDE: \(coord[0])", "LONGITUDE: \(coord[1])")
                                let coordinatesToAppend = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord[0], longitude: coord[1])
```

to:

```
print("LATITUDE: \(coord[1])", "LONGITUDE: \(coord[0])")
                                let coordinatesToAppend = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord[1], longitude: coord[0])
```

It works perfectly. Turns out I had the Latitude and Longitude wrong.